# "ValueError: Invalid control character" using Python OAuth client

Tags: python-2.7, oauth, gspread, oauth2client

I am trying to load data from a google spreadsheet into a postgres database.
The problem is when I am trying to authenticate my credentials, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_openssl_crypt.py", line 117, in from_string
pkey = crypto.load_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, parsed_pem_key)
OpenSSL.crypto.Error: [('PEM routines', 'PEM_read_bio', 'no start line')]
```

I have followed all steps in [Using OAuth2 for Authorization](http://gspread.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2.html), enabled the API and created a service account from which I got a .json file containing the necessary keys and authentication elements.

The way I am trying to authenticate is the following:

```
json_key = json.load(open('gdoc.json'),strict=False)

creds = SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(json_key['client_email'], json_key['private_key'], scope)

login = gspread.authorize(creds)
```

Perhaps the issue comes from the parameter in the json load `strict=False`, the problem is if I remove it, get the error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Invalid control character at: line 5 column 38 (char 174)
```

I saw a couple other forums and they suggest using the strict=False parameter since there are non escaped \n inside the json key file.

This is a copy of the .json key file:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "geometric-shine-118101",
  "private_key_id": "xxx",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "dataload@geometric-shine-118101.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "117076930343404252458",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/dataload%40geometric-shine-118101.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
"private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
 "client_email": "dataload@geometric-shine-118101.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
```

Copy and paste the actual values into single quotes (.e.g. '').  It worked for me.

```
'dataload@geometric-shine-118101.iam.gserviceaccount.com'

'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nxxx\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'
```